# Accessing private members inside an AlertDialog's onClick event

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm very new on Android development.

I have this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage(R.string.message_user_registered)
       .setCancelable(false)
       .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               Intent intent = 
                   new Intent(GameDescriptionActivity.this,
                              GameHomeActivity.class);

               Bundle extraData = new Bundle();
               extraData.putInt(Constants.GAME_ID, this.gameId);

               startActivity(intent);
           }
       });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

But this line doesn't work:

```
extraData.putInt(Constants.GAME_ID, this.gameId);
```

I can't get access to `this.gameId`.

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using an anonymous inner class the "this" actually refers to that class. You can refer to your main class's private fields either by removing the "this." or writing:
"NameOfYourMainClass.this.gameId"